# .htaccess Отключить чувствительность к регистру

Tags: .htaccess

На сервере есть такой файл:

```
http://test.ru/FILE_name.pdf
```

Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь, перейдя по ссылке

```
http://test.ru/file_NAME.pdf
http://test.ru/FILE_name.pdf
```

получил этот же файл ?

Разумеется файлов таких много с разными названиями, т.е. все динамично.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это ваш сервер, то достаточно двух директив из модуля [mod_speling](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_speling.html), который есть в стандартной поставке Apache.

```
CheckSpelling on
CheckCaseOnly on
```

Сам модуль может потребоваться включить, что под Debian и подобными дистрибутивами делается одной командой.

Если же сервер не ваш, а значит вы не можете использовать этот модуль, то решить проблему можно в обработчике 404 ошибки:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404handler.php
```

Сам файл будет выглядеть так:

```
<?php
$newfilename = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (is_file($newfilename)) {
    header("Location: $newfilename");
    return;
}

// дальше показываем обычную 404 страницу
readfile('404.html');
```

Этот обработчик менее гибкий: он рассчитан на то, что все файлы будут называться в малом регистре. Впрочем, не составит проблемы доработать его любой другой логикой замены регистра